# how can fix this Python Code is not defined

Tags: python

```
    surface=self.surface
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

how can fix this Python Code is not defined

## the code

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, longueur=30, largeur=15):
        self.lon = longueur
        self.lar = largeur
        self.nom = "rectangle"
def surface(self):

    return self.lon * self.lar

surface=self.surface

def affichage(self):

    print("rectangle=" + self.nom, "longueur=" + self.lon, "largeur=" + self.lar, "surface=" + self.surface)

class Carre(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, cote=10):

        Rectangle.__init__(self, cote, cote)

        self.nom = "carre"
r = Rectangle()
print(r)
c = Carre()
print(c)
```

Comment: You are attempting to access `self` outside the class. It's only defined within the class functions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. Obviously the indentation is wrong here, but it's not clear what you're expecting this code to do. If you changed the indentation on `surface = self.surface` and/or `def surface`, it either would still raise an error or wouldn't do anything. Please make a [mre] including minimal code and desired output. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: This might be helpful: [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](/q/45621722/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

At this line `surface=self.surface` you're trying to access a variable that does not exist in this scope. `self` has only been defined within the context of the various functions of your classes, and python doesn't know about it outside of those functions.

If you have an instance of `Rectangle` called for example `rect`, you can refer to its member function `surface` as `rect.surface`, or you can evaluate that function's value by calling `rect.surface()`.

The key to understanding this is to know that objects can have many names. By convention, within the object we refer to the instance by the name `self`. Outside of the object, this would be confusing so we use names that tell us what object we're referring to. (Just as you might refer to yourself as "me", but you'd be confused if others used that same word to refer to you!)

Comment: So how do I fix this error can you explain easier

Comment: I have no idea how to fix the error, since you haven't told us what it is you're trying to accomplish. I can tell you why you're getting the result you're getting, but nobody can tell you what to do about it unless you get a lot more clear on what your goal is.